# Custom role with access to particular Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-iam

**TL;DR**. I'd like to tie a role to a user, and then specify that the user can only access (read/write) cluster A, and not clusters B or C (A, B and C being all under the same Google Cloud project).

---

On Google Cloud, I have a project with multiple Kubernetes clusters (GKE-based) in it.

I need to add an auditor person to a particular Kubernetes cluster (and make sure he's not able to access other GKE clusters in the project).

So far I've created a "Auditor" role.

Now that I need to attach a role to a particular email account, I'm scratching my head. On the [IAM Admin page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project) I can tie a role to a particular email and resource type. But there's nothing that'd indicate I'm tying a role to a particular specific resource.

How do I make sure a particular user email can only access a particular GKE cluster?

Should tying a user to cluster be done from within the cluster A itself? (that'd imply that user won't see clusters B and C). If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

you should apply a custom role that permits only the clusters listing and use RBAC feature of K8s to permit al the auditor tasks on the "A" cluster.

See this docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/